# EPERM: operation not permitted

Tags: react-native, npm, npx

I was trying to create a react-native app, and ran npx react-native init but an error message Error: EPERM: operation not permitted.

````
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\ABIODUN'
command not found: react-native```
````

Comment: i have the same issue on mac m1

Answer (score 0):

Try to close and open you terminal, and startclearing npm cache then,
You should use `npx react-native init ProjectName` to create a new project.

Comment: still not good, same error